# Sublime Text 3 removes tilde (~) on save

Tags: python, django, sublimetext3

I'm working on a Django project, and I want to use Q objects as descibed in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

To keep everything readable and within 80 characters per line, I've approached it like this:

```
contains_system = Q(systems__system_name__icontains=system)
is_alert = Q(is_alert=True)
posts = Post.objects.filter(contains_system & ~is_alert)
```

This is when the weird stuff happens. It saves fine, but right after the save, the tilde (`~`) is removed. So the next time I edit the file and save it, it gets saved without the tilde, breaking my system.

I know I could do the following, but I don't like it.

```
q1 = Q(systems__system_name__icontains=system)
q2 = Q(is_alert=False)                             # Changed to False
posts = Post.objects.filter(q1 & q2)
```

I'm using Sublime Text 3 and i do not have any user settings that could affect this.
I do have [GitGutter](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter) and [Python Flake8Lint](https://github.com/dreadatour/Flake8Lint) installed. I'm on OSX Mavericks.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: I've got no idea why the '~' disappears, but you could also do  `Post.objects.filter(contains_system).exclude(is_alert)`

Comment: Yes, that would also work, and it's probably the best solution so far. Though, I think it will "filter" the query twice, and it is therefore not the optimal solution

Comment: The query is not evaluated when you do filter/exclude, see [When QuerySets are evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)

Comment: Ok, thank you both :) This makes a good solution. I would still like to know why the `~` disappears though.

Comment: Try disabling Flake8 and see if it still happens. I couldn't repeat this on Mt Lion, but my settings are likely not the same as yours.